# Spring MVC - @RequestMapping GET and POST @RequestMethod

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I understand this question has been asked previously, I am learning **Spring** following along **Spring Petclinic Sample project**. There is no problem with **processCreationForm**, when a redirect is done to **showOwner** using **GET** it works as expected, but when I experiment it by using **POST** it throws **HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported**. Is it because **processCreationForm** is doing a redirect to **showOwner** I am unable to grab it as POST request?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processCreationForm(@Valid Owner owner,
            BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "owners/ownerForm";
    } else {
        this.clinicService.saveOwner(owner);
        return "redirect:/owners/" + owner.getId();
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView showOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("owners/ownerDetails");
    mav.addObject(this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownerId));
    return mav;
}
```

Any helpful comments are appreciated.

Comment: Show how you are doing your request, because I am 99% sure you are doing a GET request to a POST endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're redirecting to `/owners/{ownerId}` url, but you didn't define a `GET` handler for that endpoint, hence Spring MVC complains with:

> HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported.

Using `RequestMethod.GET` will solve your problem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners/{ownerId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showOwner(@PathVariable("ownerId") int ownerId) { ... }
```

> Is it because processCreationForm is doing a redirect to showOwner I
>   am unable to grab it as POST request?

Since your `POST` handler on `/owners/new` is redirecting to `/owners/{ownerId}`, does not mean that redirection will be a `POST` request. Redirections are always `GET` requests.

Comment: I think there is no need to add `RequestMethod.GET`, it should take it anyways. Thank you for clarifying that, Re-directions are always `GET` requests.